# Importing camelot in Python is showing Relink error and segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-camelot

I have been using camelot to extract tables from a pdf file and the code is working fine in my local setup. But when I run the same code in my DigitalOcean droplet, this error comes up after importing camelot

```
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'                                                                                   
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried reinstalling camelot and even installed libsystemd-dev and libudev but still the error keeps coming up. Please help

Comment: Have you tried to specify which `flavor` to use when using Camelot, such as lattice vs. stream? (ie `tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf, flavor='stream')`)

Comment: @TEK just did. Same error

Comment: How did you install it? Do you have the dependencies installed as well (tk and Ghostscript)?

Comment: I installed it using pip as mentioned in the docs here https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html and both tk and ghostscript are installed as well